# Basic indentation - Python

Tags: python

```
#RockPS
import random

Choices=['R','P','S']
UserScore=0
CpuScore=0
Games=0

while Games<6:
    UserChoice=input('Rock, paper or scissors? (Type R, P or S respectively)')
    if UserChoice in Choices:
        Games+=1
CpuChoice = random.choice(Choices)   

if UserChoice == 'S' and CpuChoice == 'P':
    UserScore+=1
if UserChoice == 'P' and CpuChoice == 'R':
    UserScore+=1
if UserChoice == 'R' and CpuChoice == 'S':
    UserScore+=1
if UserChoice == 'S' and CpuChoice == 'R':
    CpuScore+=1
if UserChoice == 'P' and CpuChoice == 'S':
    CpuScore+=1
if UserChoice == 'R' and CpuChoice == 'P':
    CpuScore+=1

print(UserScore, CpuScore)
if UserScore>CpuScore:
    print('Well done, you won!')
if UserScore==CpuScore:
    print('You tied!')
if UserScore<CpuScore:
    ('Unlucky, you lost.')
```

I'm new to Python so it's likely I've missed something obvious. The program runs fine. It's a Rock, Paper or Scissors game. 5 games are played and the scores are listed at the end of the game. At the moment, it only says 1 0, 0 0, or 0 1 either way, only counting 1 game. I'm not sure why this is. I think that it is to do with my indentation as I don't  see a problem with my loop.

Comment: Note that [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommends ``lowercase_with_underscores`` for local variables - ``CapWords`` is generally reserved for classes - following these conventions make your code more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what's going on: this part of your code

```
while Games<6:
    UserChoice=input('Rock, paper or scissors? (Type R, P or S respectively)')
    if UserChoice in Choices:
        Games+=1
```

executes 6 times, but all the remaining lines from here down:

```
CpuChoice = random.choice(Choices)   

if UserChoice == 'S' and CpuChoice == 'P':
    UserScore+=1
if UserChoice == 'P' and CpuChoice == 'R':
    UserScore+=1
```

only execute once, after the loop iterations are complete. All of the `if UserChoice ==` lines should be indented so that they are part of the loop body.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your indentation does seem to be the problem. You should ident the line

```
CpuChoice = random.choice(Choices)
```

and then lines

```
if UserChoice == ...
```

to the same level as the line

```
if UserChoice in Choices:
```

The body of the `while` loop ends when the identatation returns to the same level as the `while`. So, at the moment, all your `if UserChoice == ...` conditions are only checked once, after the `while` loop has finished (which is why you are seeing `1 0`, `0 0`, or `0 1`). If you ident the lines I suggest then they will be part of the `while` loop body.